# how to put tcp data from netcat to variables?

Tags: bash, tcp, client-server, pipe, netcat

I have set up a server with the usual `nc - lk <port>` command.

My client sends tcp data to the server socket in the form of xxx,yyy which are numbers.

I want  every time the client connects that the values of xxx and yyy would be stored in variables in order to use them later.

From what I understood I must work with pipes, but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Pipe the output to a file for later reading
2. Read each line and do something with it in realtime:

For example:

```
nc -lk 8889 | while IFS=, read -a p
do echo ${p[1]} ${p[0]}
done
```